# Странности с onclick

Tags: javascript, html

Сегодня столкнулся с одной особенностью, ранее как-то не удавалось замечать это.

При клике на div мы получим очевидную надпись на экране, а точнее цифру 1. Но если мы например через просмотр кода в хроме изменим это значение и еще раз нажмем на кнопку, то на экране увидим сначала предыдущее значение (1), а уже потом новое.

`<div style="width: 100px; height: 50px; background: red;" onclick="alert(1)"></div>`

Можно ли это как-то побороть и с чем это связано вообще? Прошу прощение если вопрос ну ооочень глуп )))

Comment: Вопрос: а как это мешает в целом при разработке ПО? Планируется, что пользователь будет изменять значения через инспектор браузера?))

Comment: Ну в целом не мешает, просто увидел такую особенность и хотел узнать в чем принципе дело на будущее ))

Comment: Ого) И правда... интересно, что там на самом деле происходит, но это лечиться использованием addEventListener из скрипта вместо атрибута onclick ) P.s. Проверил через лису - а там нет такого. В хроме - так, как вы описали. Баг хрома?)

Comment: Скорее всего шаблон функции заносится куда-то в стэк событий. И когда меняется шаблон, то оно добавляется в стэк вместо того, чтоб заменяться. Т.е. как будто много раз привязали событие `addEventListener`  с разным поведением. в данном случае разный вывод сообщений в alert

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME баг хрома или недоработка лисы? :D